# htaccess Redirect 301 to new url with dynamic subdomain,protocol

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect an old url to a new url like this:

```
Redirect 301 www.domain.ro/index.php www.domain.ro/
```

But in my case i have a dynamic subdomain , and i don't know how to build the line:

```
Redirect 301 www.domain.subsdomain.ro/index.php www.domain.subsdomain.ro/
```

Now,besides that the subdomain is dynamic, also the protocol can be http or https and the user can type in the www or not, so the line would look like:

```
Redirect 301 domain.{*}.ro/index.php domain.{*}.ro/
```

{*} - wildcard that matches every alphabetic char between dots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't meed to use domain name in target when it is same as the source URL. Besides you cannot even main host name in `Redrect` directive.

Just use this rule using `mod_rewrite` to remove `index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```